# Grouping a pandas dataframe in a suitable format for creating a chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, reshape

Suppose I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
  sentiment        date
0       pos  2016-10-08
1       neu  2016-10-08
2       pos  2016-10-09
3       neg  2016-10-09
4       neg  2016-10-09
```

I can indeed create a dataframe that makes summary statistics about the sentiment column per day as follows:

```
gf=df.groupby(["date", "sentiment"]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

which gives

```
In [2]: gf
Out[2]:
         date sentiment  count
0  2016-10-08       neu      1
1  2016-10-08       pos      1
2  2016-10-09       neg      2
3  2016-10-09       pos      1
```

However I need to transform this result in the following tabular format (or new dataframe) so as to be able to make a bar chart (like for example as in [this](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0AoFkkLP2MB8kdDRrWDdLdU5mU1EzZGtTUmhwZXBJclE&mode=public&ddrp=1#) Google bar chart).

```
  date        pos neg neu  
0  2016-10-08 1    0   1      
1  2016-10-09 1    2   0
```

I tried to go about it by creating a new dataframe

```
columns = ['date','pos', 'neg', 'neu']

clean_sheet = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

and then iterating over `gf` looking for unique dates and in turn iterating on those searching for either pos, neg or neu with `.loc` but it got really messy

Any ideas for a simpler solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
gf = df.groupby(["date", "sentiment"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
#remove column name 'sentiment'
gf.columns.name = None
print (gf)
         date  neg  neu  pos
0  2016-10-08    0    1    1
1  2016-10-09    2    0    1
```

Another slowier solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
gf = df.pivot_table(index="date", columns="sentiment", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
       .reset_index()
gf.columns.name = None
print (gf)
         date  neg  neu  pos
0  2016-10-08    0    1    1
1  2016-10-09    2    0    1
```

And last solution is [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html), but in larger `DataFrame` is slowier:

```
gf = pd.crosstab( df.date, df.sentiment).reset_index()
gf.columns.name = None
print (gf)
         date  neg  neu  pos
0  2016-10-08    0    1    1
1  2016-10-09    2    0    1
```

**Timings** (pandas 0.19.0):

```
#[50000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [197]: %timeit (df.groupby(["date", "sentiment"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index())
100 loops, best of 3: 6.3 ms per loop

In [198]: %timeit (df.pivot_table(index="date", columns="sentiment", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).reset_index())
100 loops, best of 3: 12.2 ms per loop

In [199]: %timeit (pd.crosstab( df.date, df.sentiment).reset_index())
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: The pivot_table and crosstab solutions work great - Thanks! However with gf = df.groupby(["date", "sentiment"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index() I get "TypeError: unstack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'" (maybe my pandas installation is < 0.18)

Comment: Exactly. But you can omit it and use `fillna(0)` like `df.groupby(["date", "sentiment"]).size().unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()`